# Highest paying career

Tags: the-sims-3

What's the highest paying career in The Sims 3 base edition?

I mean highest hourly income, not necessarily highest weekly.

Answer (score 2):

[Criminal: Master Thief](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/careers/criminal-career-track.php) making $565 per hour, 16 hours a week ($9040)

The next highest hourly rate I spotted was [Science: Mad Scientist](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/careers/science-career-track.php) making $481 per hour, 13.5 hours a week ($6493.5)

There are more comparisons at [Career Paths List A-L](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/careers/career-paths-list-a-l.php) and [Career Paths List M-Z](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/careers/career-paths-list-m-z.php)

Note that the [Rock Star](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/careers/music-career-track.php) track makes cash based on performances ("varies in thousands")